# Python OpenCV - cv.inRange() "sensitivity"?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, color-detection

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/user/Documents/workspace/ImageProcessing/img.JPG');
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#red, blue, yellow, and gray
boundaries = [
([17, 15, 100], [50, 56, 200]),
([86, 31, 4], [220, 88, 50]),
([25, 146, 190], [62, 174, 250]),
([103, 86, 65], [145, 133, 128])]


for i, (lower, upper) in enumerate(boundaries):

    lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    cv2.imwrite(str(i) + 'image.jpg', output)
```

I am trying to isolate the colors red, blue, yellow and gray from an image (seperately).
It is working so far, however the "sensitivity" is way to low. 
The algorithm is missing some smaller color spots.
Is there a way to calibrate this?
Thanks!

edit:
input image
[image: input]

output
    [image: output1]
    [image: output2]
    [image: output3]
    [image: output4]

Comment: It would help us to understand the problem better if you can also add your input/output images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inRange` function does not have a built-in sensitivity. It only compares the values. `inRange(x,10,20)` will only give you {10,11,...,20}.

One way to overcome this is to introduce your own sensitivity measure.

```
s = 5 # for example sensitivity=5/256 color values in range [0,255]

for i, (lower, upper) in enumerate(boundaries):

    lower = np.array([color-s if color-s>-1 else 0 for color in lower], dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array([color+s if color+s<256 else 255 for color in upper], dtype="uint8")

    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    cv2.imwrite(str(i) + 'image.jpg', output)
```

Or you can smooth the image beforehand to get rid of such noisy pixels. That will make the pixel values closer to each other, so that the ones out of the boundary might get values closer to the range.

Comment: but i tried everything from sensitivity 0.01 to 200 and it doesn't get any better

Comment: everything after sensitivity = 20 is black

Comment: Yes, because your boundaries go beyond 0 and/or 255 if you have high sensitivity. You can check if sensitivity is distorting the boundaries beyond the actual possible pixel values by adding conditionals. I am updating the code for that.